# How to use Accessor as a condition in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this Accessor bellow which returns one string result  (example: 'Ready' or 'Ongoing' ...):

```
    public function getMinimumStatusAttribute()
    {
        $statusIds = [];
        $tasks = $this->tasks()->get();
        foreach ($tasks as $task) {
            array_push($statusIds, $task->task_status_id);
        }

        return taskStatus::orderBy('order', 'asc')
            ->where('operational_status', '=', true)
            ->whereIn('id', $statusIds)->value('name');
    }
```

I have `TeamleaderDeal` model :

```
return TeamleaderDeal::all();
```

which returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "teamleader_id": "8b03da5a-af1f-051d-ad6d-b6199c7f7c35",
    "created_at": "2019-09-09 11:41:46",
    "updated_at": "2019-09-14 20:57:03",
    "title": "Brand identity #2",
    "reference": "12",
    "lead_company_id": "adeddc13-6962-0a19-ac72-6713d1cf1455",
    "teamleader_company_id": 1,
    "dealphase_id": "199a34fc-de5c-038d-a655-c61fa4d97d17",
    "estimated_closing_date": null,
    "po_number": "az215487",
    "teamleader_deal_phase_id": 6,
    "dealPhase": "Refused",
    "tasksCount": 5,
    "companyLanguage": "nl",
    -------------------------
    "minimumStatus": "ready", ||||||accessor results
    -------------------------
    "invoiced": 1,
(...)
```

I would like to filter `TeamleaderDeal` results by `MinimumStatus` to show for example only results where `MinimumStatus` equal to 'Ready' ?

Thanks

Comment: Be careful. That accessor is ripe for executing N+1 queries.

Comment: agree with Martin, you better not to put the table query in your accessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
public function getMinimumStatusAttribute($minimumStatus = NULL) {
   if($minimumStatus === 'Ready') {
        // do the magic here
        $statusIds = [];
        $tasks = $this->tasks()->get();
        foreach ($tasks as $task) {
            array_push($statusIds, $task->task_status_id);
        }

        return taskStatus::orderBy('order', 'asc')
            ->where('operational_status', '=', true)
            ->whereIn('id', $statusIds)->value('name');
   }
   // else return default value
   return $this->attributes['minimum_status'];

}
```

**Edit**

Regarding your updates you may use [`reject`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections#available-methods) method provider by Laravel Collection

E.g

```
$teamleaderDeals = TeamleaderDeal::all();

return $teamleaderDeals->reject(function ($teamleaderDeal) {
    return $teamleaderDeal->minimumStatus !== 'Ready';
});
```

Comment: I added more details : it's about model results not the accessor it self

Comment: thanks it works , I added ` ->map(function ($item) {
                return $item;
            });`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this simple `where` clause:

```
return taskStatus::orderBy('order', 'asc')
            ->where('operational_status', '=', true)
            ->where('name', 'Ready')
            ->whereIn('id', $statusIds)->value('name');
```

Comment: I added more details : it's about model results not the accessor it self

Answer (score 0):

What are accessors?

Accessors create a dummy attribute on the object which you can access as if it were a database column. So if your database has user table and it has FirstName and LastName column and you need to get full name then it will be like.

Syntax of accessors:

```
get{Attribute}Attribute
```

Example :

```
public function getFullNameAttribute(){ return $this->FirstName. " ".$this->LastName;}
```

After that you can get full user name with below accessors.

```
{{ $user->full_name }}
```

After that you can get full user name with below accessors.

```
{{ $user->full_name }}
```

What is Mutator ?

Mutator is use to set value of attribute, a mutator transforms an eloquent attribute value when it is set.

How to define a mutator,

```
set{Attribute}Attribute
```

Above method on your model where {Attribute} is the "studly" cased name of the column you wish to access.

Example :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Register extends Model
{
    /**
     * Set the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */
    public function setNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['name'] = strtolower($value);
    }
}
```

Now you can use this in your controller like.

```
use App\Models\Register;

$register= Register::find(1);

$register->name = 'Websolutionstuff';
```